# Does $NP^{NP}=NP$?

Tags: complexity-theory

Is $NP$ with oracle access to $NP$ larger than just $NP$? 
As I understand $NP^
{NP}$ is just a turing machine that can make queries to an other $NP$ machine if so than $NP$ can simulate $NP^{NP}$? Is there something wrong with this argument?

Comment: The answer is _we don't know_, and the fact that we don't yet know is a pretty well established status for this problem. The class $\mathsf{NP}^{\mathsf{NP}}$ is also known as $\Sigma^{P}_2$, and is a class at the second level of the [polynomial hierarchy](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy). A simple reason why we can't just simulate an **NP** oracle with an **NP** machine is that we don't know how the **NP** machine could detect "no" instances.

Comment: Why is $NP^{NP}$ the same as $\Sigma_2^P$?

Comment: That is simply how $\Sigma_2^P$ is defined. Please read the Wikipedia page, or a textbook on computational complexity which covers the polynomial hierarchy.

Answer (score 15):

To reformulate my comments as an answer, and to expand a bit:

We don't know whether **NP<sup>NP</sup>** = **NP** — it's a notoriously open problem in complexity theory, though as with **P** versus **NP** we suspect that they are not equal. One of the reasons why we don't know how to simulate an **NP** oracle with an **NP** machine is that we don't know how the **NP** machine could detect "no" instances of problems submitted to the oracle.

The class **NP<sup>NP</sup>** is also known as $\Sigma_2^P$, and is *one of* the classes at the second level of the [polynomial hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy). The other classes at the second level are
$$\begin{align*}
\Delta_2^P &:= \mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{NP}}, \\
\Pi_2^P &:= \mathsf{coNP}^{\mathsf{NP}}.
\end{align*}$$
(All these classes would be the same if we used a **coNP** oracle; the only difference is in essence a logical negation of the output.) The classes of the third and higher levels of the hierarchy are defined by giving them yet further **NP** oracles:
$$\begin{align*}
\Delta_{k+1}^P &:= \mathsf{P}^{\,\Sigma_{k}^P} = \mathsf{P}^{\,\Pi_k^P}, \\[1ex]
\Sigma_{k+1}^P &:= \mathsf{NP}^{\,\Sigma_{k}^P} = \mathsf{NP}^{\,\Pi_k^P}, \\[1ex]
\Pi_{k+1}^P &:= \mathsf{coNP}^{\,\Sigma_{k}^P} = \mathsf{coNP}^{\,\Pi_k^P}. \\\end{align*}$$
Again, the difference between the $\Sigma_k^P$ and $\Pi_k^P$ oracles is essentially negation of its output. 
We also define $\Delta_0^P = \Sigma_0^P = \Pi_0^P = \mathsf{P}$; using the definition above, you can see that this gives us $\Delta_1^P := \mathsf{P}$,  $\Sigma_1^P := \mathsf{NP}$, and $\Pi_1^P := \mathsf{coNP}$.

The various classes of the polynomial hierarchy are thought to be distinct; that is, no matter how many layers of **NP** oracles you provide, the computational power is not thought to stabilize at any point. If **NP<sup>NP</sup>** = **NP**, then the polynomial hierarchy [collapses to it's first level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy#Relations_between_classes_in_the_polynomial_hierarchy): all of the $\Sigma_k^P$ classes for *k* ≥ 1 would be equal to **NP** (as would, for that matter, all of the $\Pi_k^P$ classes including **coNP**, as an **NP** machine could solve any problem in $\Pi_k^P$ by simulating some tower of **NP** oracles).

Answer (score 6):

$\mathsf{NP}^{\mathsf{NP}}$ is known as the second level of [polynomial hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy).

It is suspected that all levels of polynomial hierarchy are different. A machine with NP oracle can query it and negate the answer, therefore $\mathsf{NP}^{\mathsf{NP}} \supseteq \mathsf{coNP}$, while $\mathsf{NP} \supseteq \mathsf{coNP}$ seems unlikely.