# If $NP^{NP} = NP$, then the polynomial hierarchy collapses to it's first level. How to prove it?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np

From this link [Does $NP^{NP}=NP$?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2712/does-npnp-np)

I learned that if $NP^{NP} = NP$, then the polynomial hierarchy collapses to it's first level.

But how to prove it？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prove that $\Sigma_i^P = NP$ for $i \ge 2$ by induction on $i$.
The base case is $i=2$ and is trivial since, by hypothesis, $\Sigma_2^P  = NP^{NP} = NP$. For the inductive step, suppose that $\Sigma_i^P = NP$ and notice that $\Sigma_{i+1}^P = NP^{\Sigma_i^P} = NP^{NP}= NP$.

Now, for $i \ge 2$, you can observe that $NP \subseteq \Delta_{i}^P \subseteq \Pi_i^P \subseteq \Delta_{i+1}^P \subseteq \Sigma_{i+1}^P = NP$.